# Finding the highest and lowest float values entered by user

Tags: python-3.x

I'm working on a program that prompts a user to enter some floats. After the user enters their desired amount of numbers, they'll input the number 0 which ends the users input and outputs how many numbers were entered, the average of those numbers, and the sum of all numbers entered. I have all that so far but I want to also have the program output the highest and lowest float numbers that were entered by the user. How would I go about doing that? I tried using max() and min() but wouldn't work with floats from what I could tell.

Here's where my code currently stands:

```
print("Input some floats. Input 0 to exit.")

count = 0
sum1 = 0.0
number = 1.0

while number != 0 :
    number = float(input(""))
    sum1 = sum1 + number
    count += 1

if count == 0 :
    print("Input some numbers")
else:
    print("Average: ", sum1 / (count-1))
    print("Sum: ", sum1)
    print("Numbers entered: ", count)
```

Comment: You could use an array to store all the numbers entered and then find the average, sum and max/min at the end. Or, you could store the first number entered in two variables (min/max) and then update those variables whenever a number is lower or higher than them respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need list to store the inputs. See below code

```
print("Input some floats. Input 0 to exit.")

count = 0
sum1 = 0.0
number = 1.0
list_n =[]

while number != 0:
    number = float(input(""))
    sum1 = sum1 + number
    if number != 0 :
        list_n.append(number)
    count += 1

if count == 0:
    print("Input some numbers")
else:
    print("Average:", sum1 / (count-1))
    print("Sum:", sum1)
    print("Numbers entered:", count)
    print("Max: ", max(list_n))
    print("Min: ", min(list_n))
```

output:

```
Input some floats. Input 0 to exit.
4
5
8
1
0
Average: 4.5
Sum: 18.0
Numbers entered: 5
Max:  8.0
Min:  1.0
```